# How do you count regex substring matches in a dataframe, and apply it as a new feature?

Tags: python, dataframe, lambda, feature-selection

I'd like to add a feature to an existing dataframe that counts occurrences of a substring. For example, if I wanted to count occurrences of `https` within string `str`, I can do: `str.count("https")`

But how do I apply this to each row of a DataFrame?

```
Label    Text
0        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 
1        Quis https://url.com/a nunc https://g.co/b elit 
0        Donec https://url.com/c interdum libero,
0        Consectetur convallis inbox.gmail.com/d auctor.
1        Praesent  semper magna lorem
```

The desired output:

```
Label    Text                                             count_https
0        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet                        0
1        Quis https://url.com/a nunc https://g.co/b elit   2
0        Donec https://url.com/c interdum libero,            1
0        Consectetur convallis inbox.gmail.com/d auctor.     0
1        Praesent  semper magna lorem                      0
```

Here is my latest attempt to apply the new feature using `.find("https")`:

```
df.apply(lambda x: len([w for w in str(x).split() if w.find("https") != -1()]))
```

But this results in a TypeError:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: What are you expecting `-1()` to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `count` but you still want to use lambda then you can use `re`

```
import re
df.apply(lambda x: len(re.findall('https',str(x))))
```

Correcting your solution int variable can be called in this case -1() instead check for the index location which is just -1

```
df.apply(lambda x: len([w for w in str(x).split() if w.find("https") != -1]))
```

Comment: Why would one introduce a loop, a lambda and a regex, when an optimized vectorized option is available?

Comment: So it means you will downvote? OP is using lambda so it is important to clarify what he is doing wrong. I added that you can use count as well which is more straight forward

Comment: 1. Why would you assume it was me who downvoted your answer? 2. Your answer **does not** explain what OP did wrong

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it's a typo or not, but `-1()` does not make sense as it is impossible to call an integer.

Anyway, there is a better approach to achieve what you are trying to do. You can use the vectorized [`count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.count.html). A vectorized operation will almost always be faster than `apply` with a lambda.

```
df['count_https'] = df['Text'].str.count('https')
```